# Dojo charting updating axis labels on column charts

Tags: charts, dojo, axis-labels

I've built a column chart using dojo 1.4.3 ( websphere portal 7 custom dojo build ) and so far i can easily update the chart's series using the updateSeries method.

Now i need to update the axis labels everytime i update the chart's series. I've looked around and found no method to do that. Has anyone found such method or know's a workaround ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this right now as well. There's no set method to update an axis, but you can adjust the options at anytime.

```
var myAxis = this.chart.getAxis("x");
myAxis.opt.labelFunc = function (value) {
     return xAxisLabelArray[value -= 1];
};
this.chart.fullRender();
```

You have to do a fullRender on the chart after you've changed any of the options in this way.

Comment: I have a function that fills line chart's series and axis and I can call it many times (after updating my values) as long as I call chart.fullRender() in the end ;) ... It just doesn't keep my line/markers style. If I call chart.render() instead, it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the "right way" in this case is to rebuild the chart with new data. But before doing this you need to destroy an old chart (and a legend as well):

```js
  ...
  chart.destroy();
  legend.destroyRecursive(true);
  ...
```